# Deploy two applications with Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform

I succeded deploying my node.js application which is in /code/client

my /code/client/app.yml looks like:

```
runtime: nodejs10

resources:
  memory_gb: 4
  cpu: 1
  disk_size_gb: 10

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

So I can gcloud app browse to see my page.

Now, I want to upload my /code/api application. (it's a node.js with express app)

What should I do to accomplish that? I want both applications running at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a dedicated `app.yaml` for your backend app inside `/code/api` folder, and specify a `service` name in it.

Here, for example :

```yaml
runtime: nodejs10
service: api
...
```

Your backend will be served at https://api-dot-YOUR_APP.appspot.com.

But of course, you can choose another service name.

More information on [Official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuration-files)

Comment: So i'd have a service1.yaml and a service2.yaml . Then I guess I have to deploy the application from the /code folder... but the console is asking me for a .yaml file! Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I've updated my answer. You should create a dedicated `yaml` file for your `api` app, in its folder. First deploy default service (client), and then deploy `api` service.